# C Bad file descriptor issue when using accept() on sockets that is on different threads

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, networking

**What you are trying to do:**

Hello, I'm rewriting a old legacy custom http server used on a website.

**What's the issue:**

When accept is called, Can't accept client: bad file descriptor error will be outputted to the terminal even though code looks correct.

**What you tried:**

- changed orders of stuff
- I decided that my boilerplate has hidden errors can't be seen so I copied boilerplate from a random website on the internet but Im not satisfied with that so I returned back to my own code.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>

// This version of software is licensed under public domain feel free to use for any purpose
typedef struct{
    char* http_path;
    void (*function);
} location;
unsigned short server_count = 0;

/*
 * typedef struct is bad practice especially by linux convention which i try to
 * follow but for some reason program will compile or fail randomly and typedef
 * struct fixes it for some reason
*/
typedef struct{
    unsigned char running;
    unsigned id;
    unsigned locationCount;
    location* locations;
    unsigned port;    
} http_server_t;
http_server_t* servers;

char nServer(unsigned short port) {
    server_count++;
    char status = server_count;
    // The warning happens here can be disregarded
    if(server_count == 1) {
        status = (servers = malloc(sizeof(servers)*server_count));
    }else{
        status = (realloc(servers, sizeof(servers)*server_count));
    }
    if(!status){
        return -1;
    }
    servers[server_count].port = port;
    servers[server_count].running = 1;
    servers[server_count].locations = sizeof(servers[server_count].locations)*servers[server_count].locationCount+1;
    return server_count;

    
}
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    unsigned sock;
    struct sockaddr* addr;
    struct sockaddr_in inf;
} serverHandlerData;

void serveClient() {

}
void socketHandle(void* data) {
    // lazy to properly name these stuff
    // FIXME: Refactor the code here

    
   
    
    serverHandlerData *fixed = data;
    unsigned sock = fixed->sock; struct sockaddr* addr = fixed->addr;
    struct sockaddr_in in = fixed->inf;

    if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&in, sizeof(struct sockaddr))) {
        perror("Can't bind");
        return;
    } 

    if((listen(sock, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("Can't listen the socket");
        return;
    }        



    for(;;) {
        int csock;
        struct sockaddr_in caddr;
        if((csock = accept(csock, (struct sockaddr*)&caddr, (socklen_t)sizeof(struct sockaddr))) < 0) {
            perror("Can't accept client");
            return;
        }

        unsigned char* buffer = malloc(100);
        read(csock, buffer, 100);
        printf(buffer);
        close(csock);
    }
    

}
void iServers() {
    for(unsigned long x = 1; x < server_count; x++) {
        struct sockaddr_in addr;
        unsigned char status = 0;
        unsigned int sock = 0;
        if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
            perror("Socket can't be made due a error");
            return;
        }
        printf("%d", servers[x].port);

        memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
        // ipv4
        


        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        addr.sin_port = htons(servers[x].port);
        /*if((setsockopt(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, SO_REUSEADDR,
                     SO_BROADCAST, (struct socklen_t*)sizeof(SO_BROADCAST))) < 0){
                        perror("Failure while setting socket options");
                        return;
        }      */  
        serverHandlerData s;
        s.sock = sock;
        s.addr = (struct sockaddr*)&addr;
        s.inf = addr;


        pthread_t serverHandle;

        pthread_create(&serverHandle, NULL, socketHandle, &s);
        pthread_join(serverHandle, NULL);
    }
}

unsigned char running = 1;

void ctrlCHandler(){
    running = 0;
}
int main() {
    nServer(4080);
    // FIXME: Second server never gets toggled on
    nServer(1010);

    //nServer(80);

    iServers();
    return 0;
}
```

Minimal example?
I do not know what exactly triggers the error so I can't create a minimal reproducable example.

Comment: You have `if((csock = accept(csock, ...` *without* having first initialized `csock`.  The first parameter passed to `accept` should be a valid socket in the listening state so I suspect it should be `if((csock = accept(sock, ...`, maybe?

Comment: `if((csock = accept(sock,...` done but still getting bad file descriptor error after first request sent to socket, second request would fail, issue turned into bad adress error now

Comment: `status = (realloc(servers, sizeof(servers)*server_count));` is also incorrect.  You need to assign the value returned by [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc).

Comment: Similarly, you have `pthread_create(&serverHandle, NULL, socketHandle, &s);` followed *immediately* by `pthread_join(serverHandle, NULL);`: so you're effectively serializing the execution of your servers.

Comment: There are too many bugs for a reasonable answer.  You should copy your code from a more reputable source:(

Comment: Just this: 'read(csock, buffer, 100);printf(buffer);', wrong for multiple reasons:(

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the problem is that you have requested

```
listen(sock, 0); /* BAD */
```

as this sets the incoming backlog queue to 0 entries, dissalowing connection establishment.  The normal call should be (to behave as it used to)

```
listen(sock, 5); /* OK */
```

that allows up to 5 connect requests before starting to reject connections.